# DataGridView get pre-changed cell value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to get the value of a cell right before it changes. So when I do a `.Text` change, I want to grab the pre-change value before doing the text change. Is there an event that will fire allowing me to get this data?

I have tried using BeginCellEdit, CellValidating, ect... but none of these are firing, they don't even hit my break points on the method call when a value is updated.

I would rather not have to manually drop a lot of get `.Texts` during changes, and just want one event to get pre-changed values. Are there any other methods or ways to get a pre-changed cell value?

Comment: I go to the events on the DataGridView and double click the items like CellValidating which then brings me to the code method of it. Now, when I update values it is not manual, I just click a button and somewhere my program will just do a .Text =... for the change. Will that matter at all?

Comment: so for example, I click my button and it determines to update like this `frameGridView.Rows[frameNumber].Cells[1].Value = subArray[0]`, its not like I click with my mouse on a cell and change it myself. I am not if this matters or not. My CellChanged event fires just fine, but that has no prior data. (pre-changed data)

Comment: I just didn't want to have to drop a bunch of get .Texts before I change values. I am just showing a section where it shows the most previous change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a method that eliminates the need for duplicate code?

Instead of calling this:

```
frameGridView.Rows[frameNumber].Cells[1].Value = subArray[0];
```

Create a method that does what you need with the old value, before it actually updates the cell:

```
private void UpdateGrid(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, string newValue)
{
    var cell = frameGridView.Rows[frameNumber].Cells[1];

    var oldValue = Convert.ToString(cell.Value);
    // display oldValue in the section that shows recent changes

    cell.Value = newValue;  // update the cell
}
```

Then call it likewise:

```
UpdateGrid(frameNumber, 1, subArray[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope that will help you:

```
private string oldValue;
private bool isValid;

void myDataGridView_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
 this.isValid= true;
 this.oldValue= Convert.ToString(this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value);

 if (!isValid(this.myDataGridView(e))
 isValid= false;
}

void myDataGridView_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
 if (!isValid)
 this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = this.oldValue;
}
```

Comment: I said, "I have tried using BeginCellEdit, **CellValidating**", for some reason CellValidating won't fire for me.

Comment: You can requery the DataTable's data source to get the pre-changed values